# spring data jpa max aggregate function in where clause

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

i have an error with this query

```
 @Repository
    public interface DefinedAbsenceRepository extends
            JpaRepository<DefinedAbsence, Long>,
            JpaSpecificationExecutor<DefinedAbsence> {  @Query("select da from defined_absence da where da.length=?1 and max (da.from, ?2) < min (da.to , ?3) " )
        List<DefinedAbsence> getLongDefinedAbsenceWithinPeriod(
                AbsenceLength length, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
    }`
```

and this is the class

```
 public class DefinedAbsence extends BaseBean {
        public static enum AbsenceJustification {
            JUSTIFIED, UNJUSTIFIED
        }
        private LocalDateTime from;
        private LocalDateTime to;
        private AbsenceLength length;
        private String description;
    //geter()+setter()
    }
```

I use a converter for joda time

the error generated `Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select da from defined_absence da where da.length=?1 and max (da.from, ?2) < min (da.to , ?3) ]. 
[59, 70] The right expression is not a valid expression.
[72, 95] The query contains a malformed ending.`

Comment: Could you add your definition of `DefinedAbsence` and `AbsenceLength`?

Comment: I add the DefinedAbsence class , i think that i have to use " having " or "order by" because the aggregate "max" and "min" function cannot be used in th where clause

Comment: `ORDER BY` is not an aggregating clause, you mean `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the `max(a, b)` function from programming languages, which compares two values and returns the greater one, and the `MAX(expression)` aggregation function from SQL, which finds the maximum value from all result rows (possibly grouped) for a single expression.

To use `max(a, b)` and `min(a, b)` in SQL, you will have to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT da FROM defined_absence da 
  WHERE da.length = ?1 AND
  (CASE WHEN da.from > ?2 THEN da.from ELSE ?2) < (CASE WHEN da.to < ?3 THEN da.to ELSE ?3)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work fine for me :

```
@Repository
public interface DefinedAbsenceRepository extends
        JpaRepository<DefinedAbsence, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<DefinedAbsence> {

    @Query("select da from defined_absence da where da.length = ?1 and "
            + "(CASE WHEN da.from > ?2 THEN  da.from ELSE  ?4 END) < "
            + "(CASE WHEN da.to < ?3 THEN  da.to ELSE  ?5 END) ")
    List<DefinedAbsence> get(AbsenceLength length, LocalDateTime from,
            LocalDateTime to,Long f ,Long t);
}
```

i replaced "ELSE  ?2" and "ELSE  ?3" by Long attribute because I have an error with the type LocalDateTime i don't know why eclipselink cannot pass the converter ( LocalDateTime to Long )

```
public List<DefinedAbsence> get(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to) {
        return definedAbsenceRepository.get(AbsenceLength.LONG, from, to,
                from.toDateTime().getMillis(), to.toDateTime().getMillis());
    }
```